# How to create worker instances for a Ruby on Rails application using delayed_job or sidekiq with the aws-rails-provisioner gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-rails-provisioner

A standard rails app will have web servers for the front end and workers servers for background jobs. Aws-rails-provisioner is a fantastic tool, but does it support the generation of the background workers stack? I could not find out how to define it using the aws-rails-provisioner.yml file.

Comment: Would a multi-service work as defined in https://github.com/awslabs/aws-rails-provisioner/blob/main/examples/multi_service.yml? You could point to the same path with a different name. I suppose?

Comment: I agree that your suggestion should be the solution. The missing point is a way to define what service to start in each service in the yml file, the webserver in the first one and the worker in the second one. This 'rails provisioner gem' is an excellent idea, unlucky it is not being maintained anymore